# Актуальные языки программирования

Tags: любой-язык

Какие языки сейчас актуально изучать и будет актуальным в течении нескольких лет в будущем? Какой язык является по рейтингу выше, чем остальные?

Comment: традиционный комментарий: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html (открыл пачку поп-корна, жду холивар.)

Comment: Если говорить о том, "что меня ждёт через 5 лет института" и "куда поступать", то никто не ответит правду. Тенденции можно посмотреть в таких статьях, как эта [на Хабре][1], например.


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/company/hh/blog/156803/

Comment: структуры и алгоритмы нужно изучать. Это актуально всегда. А вот язык - дело второстепенное. По правде говоря, новый язык (если только идеология у него известная), изучается быстро.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Английский в ближайшей перспективе, и китайский в более далекой перспективе.

А что касается программирования то синтаксис не так важен, главное уметь правильно мыслить, а переключиться между языками не есть проблема.
Программирование это не только знания ЯП, а еще умение мыслить умение разбивать задачи на более мелкие, знание математики , аналитические способности тоже лишними не будут.

Comment: О.о я тогда программист со знанием только базы нескольких языков)

Comment: всмысле я очень не глубоко знаю только си шарп перл и паскаль)

Answer (score 4):

автор, откройте три-четыре сайта по поиску работы, вбейте в строку запроса "программист java", затем "программист c#", потом "программист c++", "программист php"...ну и так далее, насколько хватит фантазии, и изучайте выборки. Посчитайте количество вакансий, средние зарплаты, не забудьте разграничить все это по опыту работы и городу. Это вам даст относительно целостную картину того, какие языки востребованы сейчас.  Заодно поизучайте статистику по ссылке, что была приведена выше. Информация оттуда скажет вам о динамике роста/снижения популярности тех или иных языков. Это позволит хотя бы приблизительно спрогнозировать их популярность в недалеком будущем.
  На всякий случай скажу, что сейчас наиболее востребованы "мейнстримовые" языки - java, c#, php. Кроме того в России популярен 1с (хотя многие небезосновательно считают, что это не лучший выбор, наряду с php)/ Delphi, некогда на Руси весьма популярный, в последнее время сильно сдал.
    Ну и напоследок. Разумеется, не менее важно знать алгоритмы, ООП и прочие паттерны  проектирования и все, что "над" конкретными языками. Но тем не менее, просто так взять, и безболезненно перейти с одного языка на другой, просто изучив синтаксис, можно разве что в идеале - многие языки, помимо синтаксиса, имеют и обширные стандартные библиотеки, а их     в одночасье не выучить

Comment: огромное спасибо)))это лучший ответ)